# Docker: can a container execute docker ps or docker images?

Tags: node.js, express, docker

I'd like to implement a webservice to control my "docker VPS".

So I thinked to a nodejs + express script that simply execute `docker images` or `docker ps` commands responding to a web call.

But I think that I cannot execute docker commands insider a docker container, right?

What's the best approach to control container statuses from another container?

Please note that ALL my containers are 'spot-only', so user should also start from the web service, follow the logs and eventually kill it, all from API calls, so, all from inside my controller container.

What can you suggest me?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend to use directly the Docker daemon socket since it is not secure. That daemon socket has root access. It means your can do anything and more as you need.

> So in general I’d recommend thinking very carefully before making use of a Docker image that requires access to the Docker socket, even with read-only permissions as it could open your environment up to some additional risks.
>
> — [The Dangers of Docker.sock](https://raesene.github.io/blog/2016/03/06/The-Dangers-Of-Docker.sock/) by raesene

But you can use the Docker remote API (HTTP/HTTPS) if you want to secure the access to the socket:

1. You can [protect the API with HTTPS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/), it will only allow connections from clients authenticated by a certificate signed by a CA certificate)
2. The API is a REST API and uses JSON, I think it's easier to understand how to control Docker
3. Your application could be on a separated server

The API documentation can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.25/) and you can test it with cURL.

Because you use Node.js, you can use this npm package: [dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) (documentation in the `README` file) which will simplify the task :).

Answer (score 2):

you juste need to add to your `docker run` command the fact that you mount the docker socket, so

`-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

now you can launch any docker command inside the launched container

Comment: REALLY ?!!?! So simple? Thanks ! I'll try immediately